# Laravel auth routes home4 page dispaly

Tags: php

http://localhost:8000/ will display the login page. However, if I enter http://localhost:8000/home4 without being logged in as admin, it displays the respective page content please find me a way to rectify it.  Thanks in advance, I have two authentication: admin and user.  Login works fine I used single layout please help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should protect them by middleware `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {..});`

Comment: even if i put protected what about the type of user 
i used 2 tables 
admin ,user, 
when some one login from user and can directly type the url and the result will be displayed...

Comment: example home4 should access only by admin not user

Comment: Yeah i understand that condition. It will satisfy that, You want me to answer how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the unauthenticated user access you should protect the user with middleware auth like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::get('home4', 'YourController@function');
});
```

**Tip :**

Also you can also protect the entire controller by having the auth filter in the `__construct`

Here's the example

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

**Note :**

Please change your controller and function name

Comment: i used the 
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
}

this code 

but when user log's in 
he has access only to home3 and few other pages, if he type in url as  http://localhost:8000/home4 or any other admin access pages it display the page this should not happen for that please help me out .... 

and thanks for the replay and answer .

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Can you try the second solution given by me ? `public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
}` in your controller ?

Comment: public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
       $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }


if i use like this
admin can login + he has to login any of the user